# False Fetch Origin (Source Tree)

Tags: git, repository, atlassian-sourcetree, sourcetree

Currently running into the issue in Source Tree where it is saying there is a

> false fetch origin

and

> false pull origin master fatal: Couldn't find remote ref master

This issue just occurred, we have been able to make changes to the repository since it's creation but recently one of our members cannot pull/push and we think it's because one other member has access to his log in information. Source Tree only let us have 4 members to access the repo so one of our members gave his log in information to another so that he can make changes to the project. Could this be the issue?

Comment: do you connect to your GIt sever using HTTP or SSH? It sounds like your remote origin is incorrect

Comment: Log everyone out except the person in question and let him try again.

Comment: I believe it's HTTP

Comment: what do you see if you run `git remote -v`? Are these urls correct based on your remote repository?

Comment: Probabaly worth [reading this](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes) I don't use source tree but basically standard git logic should solve this issue.

Comment: I'm a bit unsure as to how to run the git remote -v

Comment: Source tree is just a UI over the GIT console. It's actually this console that does everything. Quick look though the [docs says this](https://confluence.atlassian.com/sourcetreekb/using-terminal-in-sourcetree-781398580.html)

Answer (score 0):

This error used to come if your eclipse workspace got existed unexpected while you are doing any git compare or push or pull operation.The git check out folder got locked.You need to delete that file. Same issue i had . This is how i solved this .

Search index.lock file in your checkout folder. Mostly it will be inside .git folder, Delete that index.lock file and retry . It will work.